# magento config.xml url rewrite

Tags: xml, magento, url-rewriting

I created a module and try to rewrite url by using config.xml

My URL: http://www.domain.com/mymodule/index/bestseller

I want the url to be:

```
   http://www.domain.com/bestseller
```

Below is my xml code:

```
<rewrite>
            <products_rewrite>
                <from><![CDATA[/\/(.*)/]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[mymodule/index/$1/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </products_rewrite>
        </rewrite>
```

this config.xml url rule works, but it broken all other url, all other url in the site return 404 error. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom router for that in your module.

Add this to the `config.xml` inside the `<global>` tag

```
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <[namespace]_[module]>
                    <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Controller_Router</class>
                    <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                </[namespace]_[module]>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
```

Now you need to create the router class.

in `app/code/local/[Namespace]/[Module]/Controller/Router.php` put the following code: (note: the folder name is `Controller` - don't confuse with `controllers`).

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Controller_Router
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {
    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('[namspace]_[module]', $this);
        return $this;
    }
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        if ($parts[0] == 'bestseller'){ //if the route matches 'bestseller' then internal redirect to the module
            $request->setModuleName('[modulename]') //set module name
                    ->setControllerName('index')  //set controller
                    ->setActionName('bestseller'); //set action
            $request->setAlias(
                    Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                    $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        if ($parts[0] == 'special'){ //if the route matches 'special' then internal redirect to the module
            $request->setModuleName('[modulename]') //set module name
                    ->setControllerName('index')  //set controller
                    ->setActionName('special'); //set action
            $request->setAlias(
                    Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                    $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache and give it a go.

Comment: I have another question, I actually have server url need to rewrite, for example,    mymodule/index/bestseller, mymodule/index/special, mymodule/index/latest, mymodule/index/featured etc. how can I do this?

Comment: Use the same code above and just make a `switch` statement on `$parts[0]` and depending on it's value you can redirect internally to the correct action

Comment: I've edited the answer and added an other case for when the url key is `special`. You can do the same for latest and featured

Comment: I tried this solution, but I got below error:  Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Answer (score 1):

I finally use separated rewrites like this:

```
     <rewrite>
        <rewrite_latest>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/latest.html#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/index/latest]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </rewrite_latest>
        <rewrite_popular>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/popular.html#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/index/popular]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </rewrite_popular>
        <rewrite_special>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/special.html#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/index/special]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </rewrite_special>
        <rewrite_bestseller>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/bestseller.html#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/index/bestseller]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </rewrite_bestseller>
        <rewrite_featured>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/featured.html#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/mymodule/index/featured]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </rewrite_featured>
    </rewrite>
```

it works, but looks not very good, if somebody has better solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

**Code from config.xml**

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/$#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/$1]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```